# "Нет другого выбора"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто встречаю в речи да и в литературе выражение "нет другого выбора". Насколько это правильно? Ведь можно сказать просто "нет выбора".

Comment: Меня? Нет, еще не забанили. Забанили некого behеmothus'а. )))
Здесь не сообщают конкретных причин. В профиле у него написано "невежливость". Впрочем, могу догадываться. Кто-то очень хотел приравнять тролля к тем, кто с ними борется.  
   
Вы лучше бы поинтересовались, кому помешал мой совершенно безобидный новогодний [топик][1]... 
Ерунда, конечно, переживем, но неужели так трудно было его удалить **после** НГ, если уж он так не к месту оказался на "сурьезном" форуме?

[1]: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/14413/

Comment: @tmp, задайте последний вопрос в формате *вопроса форума*: процитируйте свой новогодний топик и спросите, что в нём было плохого (или неуместного), с пометкой "стилистика".

Comment: Ещё не хватало.

Comment: @tmp, что именно спрашивал в своем новогоднем топике некто behеmothus?

Comment: Было хорошее поздравление с Новым Годом! И добрые поздравления в качестве ответов других форумчан.  Тоже удивилась, не найдя его. Проводила гостей, решила почитать новые поздравления, но, увы... А ведь в Москве Новый год еще и не наступил...

Comment: @behemothus этот вопрос не задавал. И вообще это был не вопрос, а поздравление. К которому присоединились многие форумчане, и "плюсами", и собственными ответами. Считаю, что удаление этого топика было неуважением к ним всем (((

Comment: Если кто не понял, поздравления ещё можно посмотреть здесь.
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/14413
И даже присоединится, ибо ответы добавлять позволяет.

А выказывать своё ФЕ модератору (вне специально отведенных для того мест) считаю не лучшей идеей.

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, не читается...

Comment: Видимо, по мнению модераторов, у нас должен быть исключительно деловой форум, не переходящий на личности даже в позитивном русле.         
Я поддерживаю ваше, @tmp, "фе", высказанное в сторону модераторов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В большинстве случаев такое употребление следует признать ошибочным.

Но надо быть аккуратным в оценке. 
"Выбор" (как и "альтернатива") - слово многозначное. Оно означает как сам процесс "выбирания", так и результат такого процесса. В отнешении результата такое вполне уместно.

Если мы говорим "Мой выбор - партия Любителей Русского языка", то "нет другого выбора" возможно. Если же "Мне предстоит выбор", то "нет другого выбора" - весьма сомнительно. Однако именно в подобном контексте "другой выбор" и употребляется чаще всего. Это нельзя признать правильным.

Comment: Про многозначность - очень даже верно.

Answer (score 0):

Эта одна из больных тем языка. Слова, употребляемые в речи, но абсолютно не нужные для выражения мысли называются дискурсивными.
http://postnauka.ru/video/2961

Comment: Категорически не согласен ни с тем, что дискурсивные слова не нужны для языка, ни с тем, что рассматриваемая тема как-то соотносится с такими словами.
Во-первых, дискурсивные слова это в первую очередь частицы, придающие тексту внеграмматическими способами убедительности, модальности или сослагательности.
Во-вторых, слова эти имеют дискурсивную функцию всегда, а не контекстно-зависимо как в нашем примере. 
У нас же явно контекстная избыточность, т.е. следеут говорить (или спорить) о плеоназме или тавтологичности конструкции. 





Comment: ссылка не по теме, но очень интересная.

Comment: Простите, что Вы назвали "темой"? 
К заявленной в вопросе, она конечно отношения не имеет.
Но уважаемый **Бикмаев Евгений** говорит как раз о дискурсивных словах. Правда у него несколько странный взляд на них, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, пусть будет так.

Comment: Как? Только не говорите "как сказили". Я ничего не говорил. Я спрашивал. О том, что вы понимаете под дискурсивными словами вообще и почему ссылка не в тему.

ЗЫ DocentI, с Вами совершенно невозможно общаться. 
Срашиваешь о непонятном - получаешь ответ, который вообще невозможно интерепретировать. Переспрашиваешь - получаешь рассуждения о торм, кто должен осадить назад.
Это не личные разборки. **Эта просьба отвечать на вопрос конкретно и без перехода на лисчности.** Второй не будет, если что. 


Comment: Ну и не общайтесь. Я же женщина, имею право на свои маленькие капризы! Ну не хочу и не хочу, что тут поделаешь (((  

Если смотреть не только на слова, Вы могли бы понять, что я Вас просто "отшила". Вот "такая я внезапная... противоречивая вся..."

Comment: Увадаемая! На форуме я смотрю только на слова. Физиономии меня не слишком интересуют.
С годом Змеи Вас! Хоть и не Ваш год, но так приятно поздравить.
Отшить можно только того, кто слишком много о себе думает. А мою формуную маску - это вряд ли. 
Спасибо за приятную беседу. Обещаю и впредь задавать Вам вопросы, от которых Вам будет хотеться меня отшить.  


Comment: Спасибо, что предупредили. Тогда я не буду их читать.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю,это под влиянием ритмически и фонетически сходного "нет другого выхода".

Comment: Возможно, что и под влиянием. Но вопрос-то не в этом. Насколько правильно?